# Business data connectivity metadata store is currently unavailable

Tags: 2013, external-content-type, bdc

When I tried to add **External Content Type** via sp designer, I got following error

> "business data connectivity metadata store is currently unavailable". sp2013.

I've tried many common solutions, any **unfamiliar solutions** please?

manage web app > service connectionss > BCS service application
Services on server > BDC service > started

Someone said if this file `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config>ApplicationHost.Config` has "< headerLimits > *** < / headerLimits >" this lines it might cause the error but our config file does not.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your server name has underscore '_'. If it has then rename it or connect via localhost

This does not work from SPD: http://server_name

This will work: http://localhost:9009